# Updating Kubuntu to new release

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, kubuntu, update-manager, 15.10

Beware of the beginners question.

I read about the new Kubuntu Version (15.10) that was released these days. I am using the previous release (15.04).

Is there something I need to do to get the new release version or will my system semi-automatically receive the version like the other updates I get from time to time (by getting a notification in the tray that offers me to install available updates)?

Comment: Hu? Opinion based? What? (You have 1 close vote btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this from the terminal easily enough. Open the terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -d
```

They all go on separate lines. You'll be asked for your password, this will not show anything (not even asterisks) and is normal behaviour.

Then follow any prompts and you're good to go. If you run into any problems then ask a new and specific question.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Does this imply that the auto-updater will not offer the release by tray notification?

Comment: I never waited that long. ;) If you want I can build out a VM and check for you with Kubuntu specifically.

Comment: Ok, think this question was answer by Linux. The update manager offered me to install the upgraded via tray. Fortunately I created a backup first because the 15.10 installation crashed showing three crash reports and left my system broken. I restored the backup. Not sure what to do now but I will probably open a different question about that at some point.